# Как в IDEA переименовать пересекающиеся по названию пакеты?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, namespace, package

Имеется многомодульный java-проект со следующими пакетами:

```
Module A:
    ru.site.my.source.*
Module B:
    ru.site.my.source.*
Module C:
    ru.site.my.source.*
```

Несмотря на то, что на первый взгляд эти пакеты являются разными *(потому что разнесены по разным модулям)*, по факту они являются одним пакетом.

Это создаёт проблемы. Например, если я попытаюсь переименовать пакет `ru.site.my.source.super` в `Module A`, то такой же пакет переименуется и в остальных модулях, потому что это и есть тот же самый пакет. Поэтому я сейчас пытаюсь разграничить пакеты в разных модулях, получив на выходе такой результат:

```
Module A:
    ru.site.my.source.one.*
Module B:
    ru.site.my.source.two.*
Module C:
    ru.site.my.source.three.*
```

Как я могу это сделать? Проблема в том, что это очень сложно: я не могу просто переименовать пакет в одном модуле без того, чтобы он не переименовался бы в другом. По сути приходится вручную пересоздавать структуру пакетов и вручную перетаскивать каждый класс.

Есть ли в IDEA какие-либо инструменты, которые позволят мне ускорить данный процесс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ [@Roman Konoval](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218971/roman-konoval) хорош, но не для моего случая, так как при просмотре окна `Preview refactoring` выборочное удаление изменений было запрещено *(по-видимому, IDEA просто не понимала, в каком пакете оставлять классы, которые я удалял из списка изменений, так как наш старый пакет переименовывается)*.

Задача решается довольно тривиально.

Выбираем для пакета `Refactor -> Rename`, а когда нас спрашивают, что именно мы хотим переименовать: пакет или директорию, то мы выбираем директорию. И переименовываем, например, `ru.site.my.source` в `ru.site.my.one`.

Всё, пакет стал уникальным, и теперь его можно переименовывать как угодно.

Answer (score 2):

При использовании `Refactor -> Rename...` выбирайте не `Refactor`, а `Preview`:

[image: rename preview]

Это дает возможность увидеть полный список изменений, которые операция сделает. В частности можно удалить некоторые из них, в том числе на уровне модуля, и оставить только те изменения, что вам нужны.

Comment: К сожалению он не даёт выбирать... Невозможно удалить ненужные изменения в случае, если я переименовываю пакет.

Answer (score 0):

Если проект действительно разбит на модули, то в диалоге переименования в поле Scope можно выбрать из списка модуль, в котором сейчас производится попытка рефакторинга.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]